# Is entanglement a non-unitary transformation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, unitarity

My question is motivated by the facts that measurement is a non-unitary transformation, and entanglement is necessary for measurement.

To clarify: I mean to say the transformation associated with the act of entangling two separable states. For example, in measurement, the first step is the entanglement of the apparatus' state with the state being measured.

Comment: could you better explain what you mean? How is entanglement a transformation? Entanglement is a property of states

Comment: @user2723984 - I mean to say the transformation associated with the act of entangling two separable states. For example, in measurement, the first step is the entanglement of the apparatus' state with the state being measured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A measurement is a process that takes a quantum state $\rho$ and produces a classical probability distribution on the eigenvalues of some observable $A$. Let $A=\sum_k a_k P_k$ where $a_k$ are eigenvalues of $A$ and $P_k$ are the projectors on the respective eigenspaces. Then a measurement is a channel

$$ \rho\mapsto \mathcal E(\rho)=\sum_k P_k\rho P_k$$

If you're not used to this expression, if you take $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$ a pure state and if you suppose $A$ has no degenerate eigenvalues, so that $P_k=|a_k\rangle\langle a_k|$, then this reduces to

$$ \mathcal E(\rho)=\sum_k |\langle \psi|a_k\rangle|^2 |a_k\rangle\langle a_k|$$

i.e. a classical probability distribution where the system is in the state $|a_k\rangle\langle a_k|$ with probability $|\langle \psi|a_k\rangle|^2$, this is just the Born rule.

$\mathcal E$ is a [quantum channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_channel) (its Kraus operators are simply the $P_k$), and by [Stinespring theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinespring_factorization_theorem) there exists an auxiliary system $B$, a state $\sigma_B$ and a unitary $U:AB\to AB$ such that

$$ \mathcal E(\rho)=\mathrm{Tr}_B(U\rho_A\otimes \sigma_B U^\dagger).$$

This just means that the classical probability distribution is the result of a (possibly entangling) unitary evolution of the system that is being measured *and* an auxiliary system, i.e. your measurement apparatus, followed by a lack of observation of the measurement apparatus itself. The entangling itself is unitary, the non unitarity comes from a failure to observe the whole system.

It's worth noting that none of $B$, $\sigma_B$ or $U$ are unique, they are very far from it, so for a given measurement it's not feasible in practice to see what exactly this entangling evolution was.

Answer (score 2):

In short: **entanglement is a unitary transformation.** It is essentially trivial to construct trivial unitaries that will take a product state and produce an entangled one.

Moreover, to the extent that, in your words,

> entanglement is necessary for measurement,

this is indeed correct; in this scheme, the projective non-unitary action happens exclusively *after* the measured system has become entangled with the measuring device.

Answer (score 1):

Consider for example two qubits in state $|00\rangle$. If you apply Hadamard gate on first qubit and then CNOT gate you get Bell state
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle).
$$
So, your two qubits are in entangled state now. As Hadamard gate and CNOT gate are both desribed by unitary matrix, whole transformation is unitary.

If you now apply the gates in reverse order, thanks to that CNOT and Hadamard gates are also their inverse, your qubits will be again in state $|00\rangle$. So, you are able to disentangle the qubits.

So, at least I found one unitary transformation preparing entangled entities.